# Does the term 女性語 identify words only used by women?

Tags: terminology, gender, feminine-speech

Women speak with certain word differences when compared with men and I want to verify if this term is used to describe them. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that some of those differences are fictional.

Comment: ウィキペディア has mentioned 女性語（じょせいご） in [this article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A5%B3%E6%80%A7%E8%AA%9E) already. Any reason to doubt?

Comment: @clearkimura, can you post the information as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ウィキペディア has an article called 女性語（じょせいご） in [Japanese](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A5%B3%E6%80%A7%E8%AA%9E). Quoting the first sentence and providing a translation:

> 女性語（じょせいご）とは、女性特有の言い回しや言葉。対になるものは男性語。
>
> 'jyoseigo' are those expression or word that are marked by feminine use. The opposite term is 'danseigo'.

The article also links to [this article in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_differences_in_spoken_Japanese) on Wikipedia, which mentions 女言葉 as another term. But that seems to be unused in the article in Japanese.

> [...] In Japanese, speech patterns associated with women are referred to as *onna kotoba* (女言葉?, "women's words") or *joseigo* (女性語?, "women's language").

Both terms `女性語` and `女言葉` are easily found in online dictionaries. However, I can't seem to find either one in the physical Japanese  dictionaries that I have.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be 女言葉{おんなことば}.  e.g. さようなら is used by both men and women, but ごめんあそばせ is not used by men usually.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, there is also the term [女房言葉 (*nyōbō kotoba*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ny%C5%8Db%C5%8D_kotoba).  Note that this term is not used to refer to the modern phenomenon of female-specific speech patterns.